# Update Cateogory Taxonomy Count for Attachment Post Type

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, taxonomy, attachments

For the attachment post type, I added taxonomy 'Categories'. After an import the categories have the incorrect count of attachment(s).

This [link](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-fix-category-and-comment-count-after-wordpress-import/) has a script that can be ran to fix the issue, but it requires you to run the script manually. I'm trying to find a solution I can use in a plugin or theme functions.php file that only updates the attachment post type taxonomy.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with SQL? This one worked for me.

```
UPDATE wp_term_taxonomy SET count = (
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM wp_term_relationships rel 
    LEFT JOIN wp_posts po ON (po.ID = rel.object_id) 
    WHERE 
        rel.term_taxonomy_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id 
        AND 
        wp_term_taxonomy.taxonomy NOT IN ('link_category')
        AND 
        po.post_status IN ('publish', 'future')
)
```

Comment: your answer uses wp_posts also how can I create this as a workable function in the functions.php? What hook will be used to do so?